# JavaScript: Reload the page when no audio is found

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

So, I have this very basic script that reloads the entire page when the audio stream server is down. To play the audio I use an HTML5 audio element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("ended",function() {
        location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

What I would like to do is to refresh the page every time there is no source in the element and keep refreshing until the source is back on.

I tried working with HTML5 `error` event after the page refreshes for the first time, due to the `ended` event being fired up, and the audio source is still missing causing an error. I want to "grab" this error and tell the browser to refresh again until there is no error in the audio

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("error",function() {
        location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ManoDestra I am sorry for not being clear, I edited my original question. Basicall what I need is the website to keep refreshing until the source is back on.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't posted what you've tried so far that isn't working. We can't help you, if you don't post the code that's failing. You need to at least do some of the work yourself.

Comment: @ManoDestra I edited my post again !

Comment: Why don't you use the standard <audio> attributes like "loop" and "autoplay"  [here for more reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/audio.html)

Comment: @HristoStaykov Thanks for joining. Loop makes things worse in the case of a stream failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reloading the entire page, it would be IMO better to retry the source:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio'),
    url = "path/to/audio.mp3";

audio.onerror = audio.onabort = function() {
  // show message to user about server being down/audio unavailable
  // retry -
  setTimeout(function() {
    audio.src = url;  // invokes new loading attempt
  }, 5000);           // attempts to reload every 5 seconds
};

audio.oncanplay = function() {
   // all OK
};

audio.src = url;
```